# Passing an array doesn't work in C++ the way it does in Java

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to learn C++ coming from Java, passing arrays troubles me. I have this code in my main:

```
int *newTry;
    bool won = false;
    while(!won && tries < maxTries){
        
        newTry = makeTry();

        printw("= %d =",newTry[3]); //seems to give me the 4th value okay...
        refresh();
        won = checkTry(newTry,correctSequence);
        printw("\n");

        tries++;
    }
```

These are the functions which are bugging me.

```
bool checkTry(int attempt[],int correct[])
{

    for(int i =0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        printw(" %d against %d\n", attempt[i],correct[i]); // not values from array!
        refresh();
        if (attempt[i] == correct[i])
        {
            refresh();
        }
   }
   return false;
```

}

the attempt[i] calls gives me strange value which isn't even remotely what I expect or want. I guess its some kind of pointer value or something, but how do I extract the value? I have googled pointer and stuff, but well my mind is not grasping why I do not get a value.

Complete code below.

```
<pre>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <ncurses.h>


using namespace std;
int numberOfColors, columns, maxTries;


void SetupGame()
{
    //asks some questions about the game setup.
    printw("How many colours do you want? \n[1-7]");
    refresh();
    numberOfColors = getch()-'0';
    printw("and how many columns?\n");
    refresh();
    columns= getch()-'0';;
    refresh();
    printw("and how many tries do you get?\n");
    refresh();
    maxTries= getch()-'0';;
    refresh();
}
int randomBetween(int min, int max)
{
    int random_integer;
    random_integer =  min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
    return random_integer;

}
int* randomizeSequence(int colours, int colus)
{
    int randomSequence [colus-1];
    for(int i =0; i < colus; i++)
    {
        randomSequence[i] = randomBetween(0,colours);
        printw("%d",randomSequence[i]);
        refresh();
    }
    printw("\n");
    return randomSequence;
}


void repeatWrite(string str, int times)
{
    const char * c = str.c_str();
    for(int i =0; i<times; i++)
    {
        printw(c);
    }
}
void printStart()
{
    printw (" ");
    repeatWrite("--", columns);
    printw ("\n");
    refresh();
    printw ("| ");
    repeatWrite("¤ ",columns);
    printw("|\n");
    refresh();
    printw(" ");
    repeatWrite("--", columns);
    printw("\n");
    refresh();

}
void printIntColour(int integer)
{
    // TODO (kristoffer#1#): define all colours

    init_pair(1,COLOR_BLACK,COLOR_GREEN);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("%d",integer);
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
}

int* makeTry()
{
    int trySequence[columns-1];
    printw("| ");
    repeatWrite("  ",columns);
    printw("|\r| ");
    noecho();

    for(int i =0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        trySequence[i] = getch()-'0';
        while(trySequence[i] > numberOfColors)
        {
            trySequence[i] = getch()-'0';
        }
        printIntColour(trySequence[i]);
        printw(" ");

    }
    printw("|");
    refresh();
    echo();
    return trySequence;
}
bool checkTry(int attempt[],int correct[])
{

        for(int i =0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            printw(" %d against %d\n", attempt[i],correct[i]);
            refresh();
            if (attempt[i] == correct[i])
            {
                refresh();
            }
       }
       return false;
}


int main(void)
{
    initscr();          //initiate screen from ncurses
    start_color();      //color mode on!

    srand((unsigned)time(0)); // sett the clock time as seed for the random function.

    numberOfColors = 7;
    columns =5;
    maxTries =12;

    int yes =1;
    printw ("Use standard settings 1/0? : \n");
    refresh();

    noecho();
    yes = getch()-'0';
    echo();
    refresh();

    if(yes ==0)
    {
        SetupGame();
    }
    printw("You chose %d colours %d columns %d maxtries\n" ,numberOfColors,columns,maxTries);

    refresh();
    int play =1;
    while(play==1 )
    {
        int *correctSequence = randomizeSequence(numberOfColors,columns);
        int tries = 0;
        printStart();
        bool won = false;
        while(!won && tries < maxTries){
            int *newTry;
            newTry = makeTry();

            printw("= %d =",newTry[3]);
            refresh();
            won = checkTry(newTry,correctSequence);
            printw("\n");

            tries++;
        }
        refresh();
        printw("\nplay again? 1/0\n");
        getch();
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try bool checkTry(int *attempt,int correct[])

Comment: Try building a reduced self-contained test. There are many missing pieces in your code (what is the definition of `makeTry`, what is `columns`...)

Comment: We'll need to see the code for makeTry() and also how are you declaring and initialising correctSequence?

Comment: Do you allocate memory for `newTry` and `correctSequence`?

Comment: you should put the size of the arrays attempt and correct as input parameters for your function checkTry. It will save you from buffer overflowing nightmares. Also check with a debugger if the attempt pointer has the same value as newTry

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `makeTry` returns a pointer to a stack allocated array...

Comment: As has been said, we need to see more code. We need to see the defined value for correctSequence, the defined value for column. In addition, I would always use (x*) rather than (x[]). In this case the two are the same; however, even for aesthetic purposes I would recommend the (x*) option.

Comment: As you are learning, I would suggest to use a container from the Standard library, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?

Comment: posted my complete code, also thanks for all the feedback, will try it when i get home again. @dribeas i think that may be correct. maybe i do not allocate space and therefore the memory is wiped and used for other stuff when the function is done? Having a hard time understanding this. Java abstracts EVERYTHING for me :)

Comment: you are learning some very very bad C++ habits. In C++ you should never use raw `new/delete` (you should never manually manage memory). Use standard containers (like `std::vector`).

Comment: C++ also can abstract everything. You just have to use the abstractions instead of the low level stuff. As I've said use the standard library and standard containers. Also don't use the C random library (`srand` and `rand`). Use C++ random library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to return an array in makeTry or randomizeSequence. Instead allocate to the heap with:

```
int *trySequence = new int[columns - 1];
int *randomSequence = new int[colus - 1];
```

Then you can treat it as a normal array.
In general never return arrays, always return pointers. The array's will get deallocated from the stack and, in general, this means they will work until the array's old memory space gets used again (on the next function call most likely).
If you return arrays anywhere else in your code make sure you fix that as well.

Also I'm not exactly sure if you need to subtract 1 or not.
The size of the array would be exactly columns - 1 in the first case, but if you want the size to the same as the amount of columns you don't need to subtract 1 (note that the last element in the array will still be at columns-1 in this case). So adjust your array sizes and for loops accessing them as necessary (the compiler usually doesn't check to see if the values used to access arrays are within range).

In an unrelated fix, change the last line of code in that while loop to:

```
play = getch() - '0';
```

As otherwise, the while loop is just an infinite loop.
Final note: you may want to check all your input to make sure that the user didn't put in something ridiculous.

Comment: Where should i allocate the arrays? main, class or in the functions? Edit: Thanks! changed it in the functions, not really sure why it works but it does. havent i just created pointers to an array, and wouldnt that array die after the function is done, since i only return a pointer?

Comment: @Kristoffer Arrays declared with the keyword "new" are not destroyed unless you the user destroy them. Even if you lost the pointers the memory is still not destroyed (which is called a memory leak). Arrays, however, are destroyed as soon as the scope ends. If you still don't understand, I would be glad to help out further.

Comment: I think i get it now! So in my case in the while(!won && tries < maxTries) loop i have a memory leak since i overwrite the pointer every loop and the new array i make is still in memory, i just dont know where? i wish i had reputation to vote you up, you are a great help!

Comment: You are correct, and its no problem, I'm happy to help out. To avoid such a memory leak, before you restart the loop each time simply place the following line of code: delete[] newTry;

Comment: @Kristoffer no! no! no! and no! Don't use `new/delete` !! Use `std::vector` !